# Add a Javascript Button to change content of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, iframe

I am trying to create this page where I have a single Iframe and I want to add a button to show a next page in the iframe, and a button to show the previous page in the iframe.

I have a total of 4 pages to show in the iframe named 1.html 2.html 3.html 4.html and I would like the buttons to work going from 1 to 4 and then go back to 1 and so on.

the sketch is something like this:

```
            _________
           | IFRAME  |
           |         |
           ___________


    <<previous       Next >>
```

This is a simple script that I made to change the content of the iframe

This is the iframe / Button / function.

```
<iframe id="screen" width="609" scrolling="no" height="410" frameborder="0" align="middle" name="canal" src="1.html"></iframe>


<input type="button" onclick="content2()" class="butonactual" value="See 2">

<script> function content2() { document.getElementById('screen').src = "2.html"; } </script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var locations = ["1.html", "2.html", "3.html","4.html"];
  var currentIndex = 0;
  var len = locations.length;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(':button').click(function() {
        currentIndex = this.value == "Next" ? 
                currentIndex < len - 1 ? ++currentIndex : len - 1 : 
                currentIndex > 0 ? --currentIndex : 0;
        $('#frame').attr('src', locations[currentIndex]);
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "button" value = "Previous" />&nbsp;<input type = "button" value = "Next" />
<br />
<iframe id="frame" src="1.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

■Update

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var locations = ["1.html", "2.html", "3.html","4.html"];
      var currentIndex = 0;
      var len = locations.length;
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(':button').click(function() {
            currentIndex = this.value == "Next" ? 
                currentIndex < len - 1 ? ++currentIndex : 0 : 
                currentIndex > 0 ? --currentIndex : len - 1;

            $('#frame').attr('src', locations[currentIndex]);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type = "button" value = "Previous" />&nbsp;<input type = "button" value = "Next" />
    <br />
    <iframe id="frame" src="1.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it go back to the page 1 once you are in the page 4 and you hit next?

Comment: Sure... you can do it as you like.1 sec

Comment: Hello this works perfect but is there a way to give a function to Next and other to Previous? so I could change what the button says?

Answer (score 1):

Not too difficult, just change the src tag of the iframe. Let's assume the below is your html:

```
<body>
    <!-- Assuming 1.html is the first shown, you can
         initialize it as the first src to be displayed -->
    <iframe id="frame" src="1.html"></iframe>

    <a href="#" id="prev">Previous</a> <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
</body>
```

Then you could do it as explained below:

**jQuery**

```
var currentView = 1,
    minView     = 1,
    maxView     = 4;

var changeViewNext = function() {
    if (currentView >= minView && currentView < maxView) {
        currentView++;
        $('#frame').prop('src', currentView + '.html');
    }
}

var changeViewPrev = function() {
    if (currentView <= maxView && currentView > minView) {
        currentView--;
        $('#frame').prop('src', currentView + '.html');
    }
}

// Then some click events
$('#prev').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    changeViewPrev();
}); 

$('#next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    changeViewNext();
})
```

Alternatively, just add the markup to your anchor tags to call these functions:

```
<a href="#" onClick="changeViewPrev()">Previous</a>
<a href="#" onClick="changeViewNext()">Next</a>
```

**UPDATE**

If you wanted to use buttons instead of anchor tags, leave the jQuery the same, and just change your anchor tags for buttons, as such

```
<button id="prev">Previous</button> <button id="next">Next</button>
```

**UPDATE2: Tested code using javascript only, no jQuery**

```
<body>
    <!-- Assuming 1.html is the first shown, you can
         initialize it as the first src to be displayed -->
    <iframe id="frame" src="1.html"></iframe>

    <button onClick="changeViewPrev()">Previous</button>
    <button onClick="changeViewNext()">Next</button>
    <script>
        var currentView = 1,
            minView     = 1,
            maxView     = 4,
            frame       = document.getElementById('frame');

        function changeViewNext() {
            if (currentView >= minView && currentView < maxView) {
                currentView++;
                frame.src = currentView + '.html';
            }
        }

        function changeViewPrev() {
            if (currentView <= maxView && currentView > minView) {
                currentView--;
                frame.src = currentView + '.html';
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there a way to call the function with a buttons?

Comment: of course, you can use the click bindings at the bottom of the jQuery I demonstrated, just replace your anchor tags with button tags and keep the ID references. Updated the answer for you.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work because you're not using jQuery which is what I thought. I gave you jQuery because you had tagged jquery on the tags. Please take a look at Update2 and use that code instead

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you have 4 urls and are using a single iframe. If such is the case, use an array to store the urls and a counter (which is an index into the array). When next is pressed, increment the counter and switch the iframe url. Previous decrements the counter and does the same.