# How to Make Next and Previous Buttons to Switch iFrame Pages back and forth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I made static ebook that when i click on a link it opens the html page in iFrame.Again, it is not dynamic pages.

I created Next and Previous Buttons in intend to work like that:

When the "pages/1.html" page displayed, i click on the **Next** button and it will display me the "pages/**2.html**" page at the **iframe**.

When i see "pages/2.html" and click the **Previous** button it will show me the "pages/**1.html**" at the iframe. And so on follow the numbers up and down.

I dont want to add those buttons on any iframe page i have, but to make Two Buttons **ONLY** at the **main** page that will direct to the Next and Previous Pages at the iframe.

Its kind of a simple code:

```
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
    <li><a class="link" href="./pages/1.html" target="content">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="link"  href="./pages/2.html" target="content">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="link"  href="./pages/3.html" target="content">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><button onclick="next()">Next Page</button></li>
    <li><button onclick="previous()">Previous Page</button></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

And the javascript is:

```
var pNum=1; 
var maxPage=100; 
function next(){ 
pNum++; 
if (pNum > maxPage) pNum=1; 
document.getElementById("zoome").src="page"+pNum+".htm"; 
} 
function previous(){ 
pNum++; 
if (pNum > maxPage) pNum=1; 
document.getElementById("zoome").src="page"+pNum+".htm"; 
}
```

Here is a live code: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/e07nafjn/2/)

Right now i get an error page when i click the buttons and it is not forward me to any page.

Also, not that at the JSfiddle its not even forwarding to the next page because the page is not exist ofcourse.

Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI: both buttons have their `onclick` set to `next()`

Comment: Also, see [`window.history.back()` and `window.history.forward()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Comment: Can you give me full code example?

Comment: Actually, I misread your question. That wouldn't work.

Comment: Your fiddle is setup wrong too, the javascript is set to run on page load so the next and previous functions aren't global. Change it to No-Wrap and run it again and it works as you wrote it.

Comment: Ceres, Can you show me how to implement that in my code?

Comment: Got that! Its now working on jsfiddle now but how do i implement that in my static page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work via jquery from **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204737/add-a-javascript-button-to-change-content-of-iframe)**:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var locations = ["1.html", "2.html", "3.html","4.html"];
  var currentIndex = 0;
  var len = locations.length;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(':button').click(function() {
        currentIndex = this.value == "Next" ? 
                currentIndex < len - 1 ? ++currentIndex : len - 1 : 
                currentIndex > 0 ? --currentIndex : 0;
        $('#frame').attr('src', locations[currentIndex]);
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "button" value = "Previous" />&nbsp;<input type = "button" value = "Next" />
<br />
<iframe id="frame" src="1.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Work Perfect!!**

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't provide in your fiddle an example of how we could try to simulate the paging. I searched the web and found a site which has articles separated by ids, similar to your scenario.

I focused on the next and previous functionality. The url is obviously different than that you provided, but you can easily adjust it to your needs.

Please, refer to the following snippet and see if it's what you need:

```js
var pNum = 1;
var maxPage = 100;

document.getElementById("currentPage").innerHTML = pNum;
document.getElementById("pages").innerHTML = maxPage;

this.next = function() {
  pNum++;
  if (pNum > maxPage) pNum = 1;
  document.getElementById("zoome").src = "https://www.infoq.com/articles/" + pNum;  
  document.getElementById("currentPage").innerHTML = pNum;
}

this.previous = function () {
  pNum--;
  if (pNum < 1) pNum = 1;
  document.getElementById("zoome").src = "https://www.infoq.com/articles/" + pNum;
  document.getElementById("currentPage").innerHTML = pNum;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="zoome" height="150px" width="400px" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" border="0" src="https://www.infoq.com/articles/1"></iframe>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button onclick="next()">Next Page</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button onclick="previous()">Previous Page</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      Page <span id="currentPage"></span> / <span id="pages"></span>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: OK. I will check that

Comment: C'ant get it to work. I did that: https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/03ukzz2o/ but without success. Cant see nothing on iframe and nothing changes when i click next or previous.

Comment: My example in the snippet above works. If you try to access http://coreneto.com/delete/pages/1.html it will give a 403 Forbidden. You need to make your directory browsable.

Comment: Its because of heavy attacks on my VPS server i was limited my visitors to USA and Canada only

Comment: Somehow when i click on the next button and click on another button- the next button stop effect

Comment: I used your answer to solve my problem. Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 0):

More accurate is that:

```
var pNum=1; 
var maxPage=100; 
function next(){ 
pNum++; 
if (pNum > maxPage) pNum=1; 
document.getElementById("zoome").src="./pages/"+pNum+".html"; 
} 
function previous(){ 
pNum--; 
if (pNum > maxPage) pNum=1; 
document.getElementById("zoome").src="./pages/"+pNum+".html"; 
}
```

Here is the [**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/j1c7qhm8/)

And now it works because i changed the `".htm"` to `".html"`

and the src (at the javascript) to `"./pages/"` and the src of the **iframe** to `src="./pages/0.html"`

Answer (score 0):

I have try **[that method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924715/create-previous-next-button-for-iframe-pages)**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pages=new Array();

pages[0]="./pages/0.html";
pages[1]="./pages/1.html";
pages[2]="./pages/2.html";
pages[3]="./pages/3.html";
pages[4]="./pages/4.html";

var i=0;
var end=pages.length;
end--;
function changeSrc(operation) {
if (operation=="next") {
if (i==end) {
  document.getElementById('zoome').src=pages[end];
  i=0;}
else {
  document.getElementById('zoome').src=pages[i];
  i++;}}
if (operation=="back") {
if (i==0) {
  document.getElementById('zoome').src=pages[0];
  i=end;}
else {
  document.getElementById('zoome').src=pages[i];
  i--;}}}
</script>
```

It is have the same problem: when click on link at the menu that changes the iframe, the script stop working.
But! i saw the solution someone gave there but i didnt get how he was implement that.

Here's his answer:

> This is the function that you could put before the changeSrc function:
>
> `function UpdateI(value) {i = value}`
>
> This the one click event that you would add to your links in the a
>   tag. Off course, the 4 that is sent the function in this case, would
>   be changed to whatever is appropriate for whatever ListItem is being
>   referenced:
>
> `onClick ="UpdateI(4)"`

How do i implement that method he suggest?